# How to encapsulate list that has class property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics

How to encapsulate below codes (i need refoctoring)

```
    public class mycollection
{
        private DateTime tarih;
        private int sira;
        private int visitingcount;

        public DateTime TARIH { get { return tarih; } set { tarih = value; } }
        public int SIRA { get { return sira; } set { sira = value; } }
        public int VISITINGCOUNT { get { return visitingcount; } set { visitingcount = value; } }
}
```

**i used this class below**

```
DataRow[] rows = dsChart.Tables[0].Select("TARIH>='" + DateGap1 + "' and TARIH<='" + DateGap2 + "'");

                                list = new List<mycollection>();
                                foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
                                {
                                    mycollection mycol = new mycollection();
                                    mycol.TARIH = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TARIH"].ToString());
                                    mycol.SIRA = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SIRA"].ToString());
                                    mycol.VISITINGCOUNT = Convert.ToInt32(dr["VISITINGCOUNT"].ToString());
                                    list.Add(mycol);
                                }
```

**i need like that :**

```
  public static void LoadDepartman(string departmanName)
        {
            List<StuffDepartman> li = new List<StuffDepartman>();
            GetDepartman departman = new GetDepartman();
            DataSet ds = departman.GetDepartmanA(departmanName);
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                li.Add(new StuffDepartman
                {
                    Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                    SurName = dr["SurName"].ToString(),
                    Address = dr["Address"].ToString(),
                    Phone = dr["Phone"].ToString(),
                    DepartmanName = dr["DepartmanName"].ToString(),
                    Salary =int.Parse( dr["Salary"].ToString()),
                    Married = dr["Married"].ToString()
                }
                );
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Stuffs"] = li;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

(I don't fully understand how the first two examples relate to the third... they don't seem to share anything in common)

So what currently breaks? The biggest issue I can see is that (IIRC) to be *reliably* usable with `Session` (with different back end implementations) the item must be serializable (var `BinaryFormatter`), but that may be as simple as marking `mycollection` with `[Serializable]`.

For info `mycollection` is a confusing name for something that is a **row entity**, not the actual collection - and if you have C# 3.0 you could simplify things a bit with automattically implemented properties:

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeSensibleName
{
    public DateTime Tarih {get;set;}
    public int Sira {get;set;}
    public int VisitCount {get;set;}
}
```

However; it isn't clear (from your code) whether this will change anything. Please can you clarify what is currently happening?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is the refactoring you are looking for:

```
DataRow[] rows = dsChart.Tables[0].Select("TARIH >='" + DateGap1 + "' and TARIH <='" + DateGap2 + "'");
List<mycollection> list = new List<mycollection>();
foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
{
    list.Add(new mycollection
    {   
      TARIH = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TARIH"].ToString());
      SIRA = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SIRA"].ToString());
      VISITINGCOUNT = Convert.ToInt32(dr["VISITINGCOUNT"].ToString());
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that in order for this to work you need to be running the .NET Framework 3.x (VS2008).

Comment: That's what I understood from the question as well +1